# iPhone - Width of path based on velocity of touch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making use of velocityInView with UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093544/making-use-of-velocityinview-with-uipangesturerecognizer)

I am creating an app in which I am drawing a path based on touchMoved. I want to make the width of line based on the velocity of touch. I can achieve this effect, but there is no smoothness in this.

CODE:

```
-(float) clampf:(float) v: (float) min: (float) max 
{
    if( v < min ) v = min;
    if( v > max ) v = max;

    return v;
}

- (float)extractSize:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{
    vel = [gesture velocityInView:self.view];
    mag = sqrtf((vel.x * vel.x) + (vel.y * vel.y)); // pythagoras theorem (a(square) + b(square) = c(square))
    final = mag/166.0f;
    final = [self clampf:final :1 :40];
    NSLog(@"%f", final);

    if ([velocities count] > 1) {
        final =  final * 0.2f + [[velocities objectAtIndex:[velocities count] - 1] floatValue] * 0.8f;
    }
    [velocities addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:final]];
    return final;
}
```

But i am getting something like this:

[image]

Comment: This might be helpful to you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093544/making-use-of-velocityinview-with-uipangesturerecognizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093544/making-use-of-velocityinview-with-uipangesturerecognizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the similar effect before. I was using the original touch event methods (`touchesBegan`, etc.) and calculated the velocity by myself. Every thing looks all right.

I am not sure if the `velocityInView` method always gives your the correct result during user moving their finger, maybe you should try to calculate the velocity by yourself and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: will you please tell me how to calculate the velocity of touchMoved?